# How to start Blazor Server App programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to start Blazor Server App on local machine programmatically through a console project or through clicking a button in a windows application?

Some like open the Blazor Server App project in VS and then click "debug" button.

Comment: Is your Blazor app hosted on a server? What's the OS / hosting environment? Or are you trying to run it locally on your machine? In debug mode? Please edit your question with details to answer these questions.

Comment: run it locally. I have modifed my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, below is a dummy example starting it in a new thread, it's possible to start in the same thread the process but recommended to isolate started processes separately that the one running the initiator, how to decide? Read a bit about multithreading and memory management, I don't know the correct answer.

Below piece is running the csproj but in the same way a .dll can be executed with [dotnet command.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run)

```
/// <summary>
/// Starts dotnet app in a new thread
/// </summary>
/// <param name="folder">"d:/whatever"</param>
/// <param name="project">"MyBlazor.Company.Whatever"</param>
/// <returns>Thread wrapping the process running the project</returns>
public Thread StartDotnetThread(string folder, string project)
{

    string arguments = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, " run -p {0}", Path.Combine(folder, project));

    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("dotnet")
    {
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
        ErrorDialog = true,
        CreateNoWindow = false,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        Arguments = arguments
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        using Process process = Process.Start(info);
        process.WaitForExit();

        // to stop the process
        // process.Kill();
    });
    
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();

    // wait 1 second
    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();

    // Aborting the thread 
    // thread.Abort()

    return thread;
}
```